# Write binary string with as little bytes as possible

Tags: java, file, storage

I have a binary string (ex. `"010110111101110101"`), the length is always fixed at `88` (always with leading zeroes).

If I write `myString.getBytes()` the size is `88 B`.

How can I write this String to a file efficiently (use as little space as possible)?

Comment: Your are already writing a binary file, what was you expecting?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question

Comment: Write it not as a string but as a binary number? I'm struggling to understand what the question is.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. I've never, in years of programming experience, found a use case where I had to use a string filles of '0' and '1' characters. You should probably use a Bitset, or a byte array, or a BigInteger. Hard to say without knowing what you're doing with this string, where it comes from and why you need it.

Comment: Just to be pedantic (which we *should* be when talking about code), that's not a "88 byte binary string", that is a string containing the base-2 string representation of a number.  That number could be represented as 11 bytes.  At least.  I *think* that's what you mean.  It's hard to tell.